# Rails - JSON passing to controller evaluates to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to pass a JSON to a controller as a parameter in my Rails app, but it consistently throws errors saying that the parameter is nil.

The JSON is assembled by user input in a view, and is passed to the controller via a click on the `#summary` element like so:

```
var url = $('#summary').attr('href') + '?report={datetime:"2016-06-13 08:38:04",weather_id:"1",location_description:"home",latitude:"12",longitude:"34",accuracy:"56",wildlife:"cat",comments:"test",report_type_id:"1",wetland_feature_id:"1",wetland_number:"101"}';
$('#summary').attr('href', url);
```

And, after clicking `#summary`, the view from my console:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in?report={datetime:%222016-06-13%2008:38:04%22,weather_id:%221%22,location_description:%22home%22,latitude:%2212%22,longitude:%2234%22,accuracy:%2256%22,wildlife:%22cat%22,comments:%22test%22,report_type_id:%221%22,wetland_feature_id:%221%22,wetland_number:%22101%22}" for ::1 at 2016-06-13 16:58:26 -0400
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
Parameters: {"report"=>"{datetime:\"2016-06-13 08:38:04\",weather_id:\"1\",location_description:\"home\",latitude:\"12\",longitude:\"34\",accuracy:\"56\",wildlife:\"cat\",comments:\"test\",report_type_id:\"1\",wetland_feature_id:\"1\",wetland_number:\"101\"}"}
```

Finally, in the controller, I try to get the JSON back out with

```
@incomingReport = (params[:report])
```

but @incomingReport consistently evaluates to `nil`, for example `NoMethodError (undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass)` when I tried to do `@incomingReport.each`.  I did some other tests as well, such as

```
if (params[:report]).nil?
    puts "Yep, nil"
end
```

which, sure enough, printed `Yep, nil` to my console.

I'm sure that there is something wrong with the way that I'm formatting the param in the first place, but I'm not sure what.  Any help would be much appreciated.

**Editing to show more controller code**

```
def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)

    incomingReport = params[:report]
    puts incomingReport

    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end

private
def report_params(params)
    params.permit(:user_id, :report_type_id, :datetime, :weather_id, :location_description, :latitude, :longitude, :accuracy, :comments, :wildlife, :other_weather, :wetland_feature_id, :other_wetland_feature, :wetland_number)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access the query params use URI and CGI libraries

```
url    = 'http://www.foo.com?id=4&empid=6'
uri    = URI.parse(url)
params = CGI.parse(uri.query)
# params is now {"id"=>["4"], "empid"=>["6"]}

id     = params['id'].first
# id is now "4"
```

That said I think this is a dirty solution to the problem you have but it is what you asked for.

to allow your existing controller to access this param you can change this:

```
def report_params(params)
  params.permit(:user_id, :report_type_id, :datetime, :weather_id, :location_description, :latitude, :longitude, :accuracy, :comments, :wildlife, :other_weather, :wetland_feature_id, :other_wetland_feature, :wetland_number)
end
```

to

```
def report_params(params)
  params.permit(:user_id, :report_type_id, :datetime, :weather_id, :location_description, :latitude, :longitude, :accuracy, :comments, :wildlife, :other_weather, :wetland_feature_id, :other_wetland_feature, :wetland_number, :report)
end
```

Comment: Hmm... would this have anything to do with the fact that the controller in question is tied to the Devise new_user_session path?  I tested this out with other controllers and it works fine - only this controller spits nil at me, no matter what I put into it.

Comment: Do you have strong params on that controller by chance?  Can you post your controller code?

Comment: Edited the code above to include the controller and whitelist

Comment: that is your problem.  report is not on the list of acceptable params.  I edited my answer with the change to report_params that you will need to get this done.

Comment: @ruby_newbie strong params is not the issue. It only works if you access the params using the private method with whitelisted params. The plain `params` hash still has all params

Comment: @ruby_newbie - thank you, but as Kkulikovskis' comment suggests, this is still not working.  I literally took the same code and dropped it into another controller and it worked fine.

Comment: I think I will repost with a more clear explanation, now that I understand the problem a little better.